# Error using install_git: Unsupported URL protocol

Tags: r, git

Using R, I am trying to install a local version of a cloned repo, using the following commands:

```
library(devtools)
install_git("/home/my_local_url/.git", ref = "mindepth_order")
```

but I get the error message:

```
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from Git:
  Error in 'git2r_remote_ls': unsupported URL protocol
```

This used to work, but I have not used the system for a while. Many Stackoverflow users have reported the same or similar errors, but typically installing from a remote server. I have followed any instructions I have found, but nothing has worked. It is reported that this error is related to SSH not being available. This is what I have tried so far:

- reinstalled devtools to get the latest version
- reinstalled git2r
- run install_git with the additional argument: credentials=git2r::cred_user_pass("user", "password")
- run_libgit2_features() producing the following output, showing that ssh is available:

  $threads
  [1] FALSE

  $https
  [1] TRUE

  $ssh
  [1] TRUE

I do not know what else to try.

Comment: What OS are you using? Have you tried `install_git("file:///home/my_local_url/.git", ref = "mindepth_order")`

Comment: @MrFlick that worked! Thank you! If you would like to add your comment as an answer I will accept it. I am on CentOS Linux 7.